# Is it correct to say "The claws or sides of the hairclip" in everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

In the dictionary

> [claw](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/claw_1?q=claw)(noun): part of a tool or machine, like a claw, used for holding,
> pulling or lifting things

I am not sure the 2 ides/parts of a hairclip are called "**claws**".

Is it correct to say "**The claws or sides of the hairclip**" in everyday conversations?

**Note**: some women say they are "**the teeth of the hairclip**"

Comment: The two sides of the clip each consist of a row of - I would call them _teeth_ too, but _claws_ would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, "teeth", "claws", "prongs", "grippy bits"... There's No well-established term that I am aware of, though there may be one used by hairgrip designers and manufacturers.  It is just not something that comes up in everyday conversations very often.

> Oh look one of the grippy bits has broken off my pink hairgrip. What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to refer to those specifically, I would call them [**tines**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tine).

> 1 : a slender pointed projecting part : prong

as in "Look, my hairclip has a broken tine."

This word does seem to be in actual usage, for example in [US Patent US7066185B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7066185?oq=hair%20clip%20tines):

> The legs each have a tine base and a number of curved tines...